# How to save images generated by PyTorch DataLoader?

Tags: python, pytorch, transformation, dataloader, pytorch-dataloader

I'm trying to add transforms to a video dataset I have, and I've already extracted the frames. I want to add the transforms but instead of saving to the variable to a Dataloader, I would like to export all the transforms as images to a new directory so I can use it to train a model with Video Swin Transformer - https://github.com/SwinTransformer/Video-Swin-Transformer

How can I save the images?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply iterate through the dataloader having the transform applied to it and store or directly save each frame in the generated batch.

Something like this:

```
transformed_images = []
for batch in dataloader:
    for video in batch:
        for frame in video:
            transformed_images.append(image)
```

Depending on where the sequence dimension is in your data